# Are there any JavaScript MVC frameworks that have no external dependencies?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

Does anyone know of a MVC framework in JavaScript that is free of other library dependencies?
I'm thinking along the lines of backbone.s or spine.js both of which CLAIM to have no dependancies but then their code clearly uses jQuery or Zepto functions.
I'm after one that uses native JavaScript only and therefore can be used with any framework (jQuery, MooTools, Dojo OR NO FRAMEWORK)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), it's not MVC - it's MVVM and solved most of my complex ui code in javascript. Knockout is like the glue between the data, events and the widgets - it helps write clean and easy to maintain JS interfaces.

Last but not least it is not tied to any other library, pure JS.

Comment: knockout is awesome.  saw this question an immediately thought of it as a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at: http://www.sproutcore.com/ or http://cappuccino.org/ ? They're a bit more than just MVC frameworks but they do not rely on other libraries as far as I can tell. I'm searching for the same and these maybe overkill, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I second that lol, however, he those are all that I can think of to meet the requirements. :)